# How to input / start a new line in bash terminal?

Tags: bash, line-editor

I notice some sample bash for loops are spread out over multiple lines in examples

```
for VARIABLE in file1 file2 file3
do
    command1 on $VARIABLE
    command2
    commandN
done
```

(eg here
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/) How do I enter a newline in the bash terminal (I use putty) ? When I press enter at the end of a line the system executes it.

Comment: Also in `bash` you can use the keyboard combination `Ctrl + x + e` to open the contents of the command prompt in a editor such as vim where you can work on it more easily, when you're done you can exit the editor and the command will run.

Comment: Related answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232912/what-is-the-effect-of-a-lone-backtick-at-the-end-of-a-command-line/345006#345006

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of:

```
for VARIABLE in file1 file2 file3
```

The shell can't execute anything since that `for` loop is not finished. So instead, it will print a different prompt, the `$PS2` prompt (generally `>`), until you enter the closing `done`.

However, after `>` is displayed, you can't go back to edit the first line.

Alternatively, instead of typing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you can type <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd>. That way, the newline character (aka `^J`) is entered without the current buffer being *accepted*, and you can then go back to editing the first line later on.

In `zsh`, you can press <kbd>Alt-Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a newline character without accepting the current buffer. To get the same behavior in `bash`, you can add to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e\C-m": "\026\n"
```

(`\026` being the `^V` character).

Comment: `Ctrl-J` to start, and `Ctrl-D` to finish, ended up working well for me.