# What is the effect of a lone backtick at the end of a command line?

Tags: shell, command-line

I accidentally typed in cd ` into terminal today and terminal didstrange things.

It put a "> " signed on the next line followed by my cursor like it wanted some input. No matter what I entered continued to do the same thing until I terminated the command.

Out of curiosity what happened? Was this a bug or a feature?

Comment: When you do such a mistake, use Ctrl-C to break out of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered here [already](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27432/14035)... essentially

> Everything you type between backticks is evaluated (executed) by the shell before the main command

Comment: I had read that and tried typing commands to no effect. Your post made me think to try another backtick, which acted as in the other post.

Answer (score 4):

The effect you witnessed is due to the shell expecting another backtick. You get the same effect when you, for example, enter `(` (or any other incomplete command) and press <kbd>Return</kbd> on the command line.

The prompt, `>␣`, that you got is the *secondary prompt*, as stored in `$PS2`. This prompt is used by the shell when more interactive input is needed to finally complete the command.

An example:

```
bash-4.4$ for i in {0..10..2}
> do
> printf 'Hello %d\n' "$i"
> done
Hello 0
Hello 2
Hello 4
Hello 6
Hello 8
Hello 10
bash-4.4$
```

`bash-4.4$` is my *primary prompt* (`$PS1`), and I get the secondary prompt when pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> after `{0..10..2}` on the first line since the command typed in so far is not complete. I continue to get the secondary prompt on each line until I have completed the command by pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> after `done` (which completes the input of the for-loop to the shell).

The *tertiary prompt* (`$PS3`, usually `#?␣`) is used by the `select` keyword, while the *quaternary<sup>1</sup> prompt* (`$PS4`, usually `+␣`) is used for tracing output when the shell `xtrace` option is set with `set -x`.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Yes, I had to look up that word.</sub>