# Fix command when it accidently had a trailing single-quote?

Tags: bash

I do this a lot:

```
user@machine: $ ls'
>
# Me: Argh! I did it again!
>'

: No such file or directory
```

Basically, I finish typing a command, and hit <kbd>'</kbd> by accident when trying to hit enter, and end up with an un-closed single-quote. I can't get back up to the previously line to delete it, so end up just running the command with a syntax error.

Is there a way to recover this and fix my command?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232912/what-is-the-effect-of-a-lone-backtick-at-the-end-of-a-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> instead to avoid running the command, then the up arrow and <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> to remove the offending quote.

Comment: I thought ctrl + c was only for interrupting a command *after* it was executing. I guess I erroneously assumed it would log me out of my shell or something if nothing was running.

Comment: @Scribblemacher Technically, it *is* interrupting an executing command: the shell. The shell, however, catches the signal and, instead of exiting, simply cancels the current input and displays the next prompt.