# What is percent sign prompt in a shell?

Tags: shell, command-line, prompt

While watching a video, I saw the following:

```
% more tinyUF.txt
10
4 3
3 8
6 5
```

What is this `%` sign before `more` command?

Comment: `export PS1=%` ??

Comment: @RomanGräf, what's that?

Comment: You can change the normal `$` sign using `export PS1=...` where `...` is the replacement.

Comment: @RomanGräf, I see, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Roman Gräf: You can actually do a whole lot more with the prompt than just change the character.  Mine includes the machine name (since I often have xterm windows into other machines) and the last few directories in the current path.  And if I'm root, it becomes bright red.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That's the shell prompt, or more precisely, it's the shell's *primary* prompt ([there are several](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345006/116858)).  It's the shell's way of saying, "*go ahead, I'm ready for input now*".

The `%` prompt is common in `csh`-type shells and in the `zsh` shell, while `sh`-shells (like `bash` and `ksh93`) ordinarily use a `$` as the prompt.

The prompt usually changes to `#` for the root user since *a sufficiently powerful user should be reminded of that power by having an alternate prompt* (as the POSIX standard puts it).

The primary prompt in `sh`-type shells is determined by the value of the shell variable `PS1`.

---

Summary of the comments below, with additions:

The `#` character of the root prompt (used by both `sh` and `csh` shells) coincides with the familiar shell comment character. Copying and pasting a command as root would render the pasted command inoperable if a user also copied the shell prompt. Note that `#` was adopted as the root prompt before the shell had a comment convention (reference: [email from Doug McIlroy](https://www.tuhs.org/pipermail/tuhs/2017-April/011286.html)).

The `es` and `rc` shells of Plan 9 use the `;` character as the default prompt. A consequence of this is that copying and pasting a command, including the prompt, will still mean that the pasted command is valid (and it will be executed).

A way for enabling one to have a custom, but still copy-pastable, shell prompt would be to use `: something ;` , where `something` could be the current directory, hostname or time, for example.

Comment: Also in `zsh` (a Bourne-style shell, but with lots of features from `tcsh`). Note that Bourne-like and csh-like shells typically use `#` for users of uid 0.

Comment: Also note that `rc`-like shells use `;` there (one can copy-paste the full line and that's valid shell code, same idea as root's `#` prompt being a comment).

Comment: a very important choice of # for root is that if you copy a command including it you will not cause damages (as # starts a comment, so will comment your command (well, its first line)). Some people use ">" and if you copy it as well, it can clobber (empty completely) binaries if the command has a full or relative path or if you are in the right directory (and have sufficient rights, for example if you are root). I have seen this happen.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Didn't the #-for-root convention originate a _long_ time before terminals where cutting-and-pasting an entire line is easily possible became common?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes. It originated even before csh introduced # as a comment leader. Still, it's true that `#...` lines are comments when copy-pasted even if it was not the intention. I don't know if it was the intention behind `;` in `rc` either, though I observe it's a convenient consequence.

Comment: It would be more correct to say Bourne-like than `sh`-type. The Thomson shell (`sh` until Unix v6 before it was replaced by the Bourne shell in v7) had `%`/`#` as well. I do not know why the Bourne shell changed it to `$`. Possibly to make it clear to the user that they were getting a different shell from what they would be used to before. Note that `#` as a comment leader was introduced by csh. The Bourne shell had no comments until much later (you'd use the `:` null-command as an ersatz).

Comment: It looks like `sh` in [PDP-7 Unix](https://github.com/DoctorWkt/pdp7-unix) and [Unix V1](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V1/sh.s) had `@`/`#` before it was changed to `%`/`#` ([v5 had `%`](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V5/usr/source/s2/sh.c), but I didn't find what it was for v2, v3, v4).

Comment: IIRC, in early Unices, `@` was also the `kill` character (now ^U) and `#` was erase (now ^H or ^?), so if the early ttys had had the capability to copy-paste, that would have caused interesting behaviours